# Dropwizard Metrics Performance overhead in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dropwizard, metrics

I am using dropwizard metrics in Spring boot REST service,

```
    <!--Dropwizard Metrics for Spring-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ryantenney.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

// MetricsConfig.java

```
import com.codahale.metrics.ConsoleReporter;
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.EnableMetrics;
import com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.MetricsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    @Configuration
    @EnableMetrics(proxyTargetClass = true)
    public class MetricsConfig extends MetricsConfigurerAdapter {

         @Override

        public void configureReporters(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
            // registerReporter allows the MetricsConfigurerAdapter to
            // shut down the reporter when the Spring context is closed
            registerReporter(ConsoleReporter
                    .forRegistry(metricRegistry)
                    .build())
                    .start(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }

}
```

From the configuration above, every hour dropwizard will spit out metrics to Console, so meanwhile, Where does dropwizard metrics stores and captures the metrics data? Is it Java heap and whats the performance impact there and a way to fine tune this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is stored in Java Heap and will go away once the server is restarted.

The performance impact should not be much and should normally outweigh the benefits of having such a metrics